# Creating XSLT transform to flatten multiRef encoded SOAP message

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

Input is a mutliRef encoded SOAP message/document.  How do you use
XSLT to flatten multiRefs.  Multiref nodes can be referenced used
multiple times, and themselves recursively reference other multiRef
nodes.

The only pieces of the structure that are safe to refer to, are
multiRef elements and @id and @href attributes.  Other elements or
namespaces could change.

Sample input message is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:getAccountDTOResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/pw/services/PWServices">
      <getAccountDTOReturn href="#id0" />
    </ns1:getAccountDTOResponse>
    <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0"
    soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xsi:type="ns2:Account"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices">
      <ID href="#id1" />
      <accountNumber xsi:type="soapenc:string"></accountNumber>
      <accountType xsi:type="soapenc:string"></accountType>
      <clientData xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xsi:nil="true" />
      <name xsi:type="soapenc:string"></name>
      <parentRef xsi:type="soapenc:string"></parentRef>
    </multiRef>
    <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0"
    soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xsi:type="xsd:long"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    0</multiRef>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Expected output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:getAccountDTOResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/pw/services/PWServices"
    soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

      <getAccountDTOReturn xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices"
      soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      xsi:type="ns2:Account">
        <ns1:ID soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xsi:type="xsd:long">0</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:accountNumber xsi:type="soapenc:string" />
        <ns1:accountType xsi:type="soapenc:string" />
        <ns1:clientData xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xsi:nil="true" />
        <ns1:name xsi:type="soapenc:string" />
        <ns1:parentRef xsi:type="soapenc:string" />
      </getAccountDTOReturn>
    </ns1:getAccountDTOResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Update:**
In the example above, logically, what should happen is:

On the first pass, getAccountDTOResponse contains @href="#id0", so that element is replaced with all the children multiRef element with @id="id0", with exception of.

On the second pass, @href="#id1" should be discovered, and ID element should be replaced with contents of element with @id="id1".

No multiRef elements should exists in the output.  No attributes @id or @href should exists in output, if there were involved in this whole multiRef mess.

Comment: It is not very clear what exactly should go into what. Could you, please, add this to your question?

Comment: @Dimitre I added some clarification to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alex, I'm not matching your output completely but here is how you can resolve your document by hrefs.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" >

    <xsl:key name="multiref-by-id" match="multiRef" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(@href, '#')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |
             key('multiref-by-id', substring-after(@href, '#'))/@* |
            key('multiref-by-id', substring-after(@href, '#'))/node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@href[starts-with(., '#')] | multiRef[@id] | @soapenc:root"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:getAccountDTOResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                                   xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/pw/services/PWServices">
            <getAccountDTOReturn href="#id0"/>
        </ns1:getAccountDTOResponse>
        <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0"
                  soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                  xsi:type="ns2:Account"
                  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                  xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices">
            <ID href="#id1"/>
            <accountNumber xsi:type="soapenc:string"></accountNumber>
            <accountType xsi:type="soapenc:string"></accountType>
            <clientData xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xsi:nil="true"/>
            <name xsi:type="soapenc:string"></name>
            <parentRef xsi:type="soapenc:string"></parentRef>
        </multiRef>
        <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0"
                  soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                  xsi:type="xsd:long"
                  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            0
        </multiRef>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Produces the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:getAccountDTOResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/pw/services/PWServices"
                                   soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <getAccountDTOReturn id="id0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                                 xsi:type="ns2:Account">
                <ID xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices" id="id1"
                    soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="xsd:long">
                    0
                </ID>
                <accountNumber xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices"
                               xsi:type="soapenc:string"/>
                <accountType xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices"
                             xsi:type="soapenc:string"/>
                <clientData xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices"
                            xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xsi:nil="true"/>
                <name xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices"
                      xsi:type="soapenc:string"/>
                <parentRef xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices"
                           xsi:type="soapenc:string"/>
            </getAccountDTOReturn>
        </ns1:getAccountDTOResponse>


    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I think that this apporach could be easily customized to fit your needs. I would like to outline that the provided stylesheet operates on `@hrefs` and does not take in account any element names. Therefore it can be used flexibly without paying attention to the referring element names. However all the reference should be named `multiRef`s but this can be easily customized too.

Comment: Think this is right.  Think one of the differences is not removing @id attributes from the output, and the other is my sample output has references to ns1 namespace that, not sure from where.  That may be a bug in the imperative version of this function.

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <xsl:key name="kMultiRefById" match="multiRef" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="getAccountDTOReturn">
        <xsl:variable name="vRefer"
                      select="key('kMultiRefById',substring(@href,2))"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$vRefer/namespace::*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$vRefer/@*|$vRefer/node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="multiRef|multiRef/@id|multiRef/@soapenc:root"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:getAccountDTOResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                                   xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/pw/services/PWServices">
            <getAccountDTOReturn soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                                 xsi:type="ns2:Account"
                                 xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                                 xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices">
                <ID href="#id1"></ID>
                <accountNumber xsi:type="soapenc:string"></accountNumber>
                <accountType xsi:type="soapenc:string"></accountType>
                <clientData xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xsi:nil="true"></clientData>
                <name xsi:type="soapenc:string"></name>
                <parentRef xsi:type="soapenc:string"></parentRef>
            </getAccountDTOReturn>
        </ns1:getAccountDTOResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Note**: Keys for cross references. Identity rule. Empty rules for stripping. **Copying namespaces nodes might not be posible for every XSLT processor**, although I only know about Mozilla's TransforMiiX wich doesn't have implemented `namespaces::` axis.

Comment: This is close, but not quite complete. In the ID element, href="#id1" is not resolved.  Also, can't relie on getAccountDTOReturn, becouse it will change, I think match would have to be based on @href existing.